# Moving mouth animation android

Tags: android, animation

I want to make a moving mouth animation in android similiar too a animation like annoying orange. 
How can i make a similar animation in android ?
Should i make a picture after picture animation or are the any easier solution ?

Comment: easier than displaying multiple pictures one after the other? I'm afraid, you're expecting too much

Comment: how much easier than animating a sequence of images can it get ?